# Permissions for Wordpress

Tags: permissions, wordpress

What are the correct permissions to give my wordpress files on a clean install?

I don't use users, I do everything with my root account.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this might be correct unless something changed recently:

[Answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress) by [Manuel Schneid3r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978486/manuelschneid3r):

> When you setup WP you (the webserver) may need write access to the
>   files. So the access rights may need to be loose.
>
> ```
> chown www-data:www-data  -R * # Let Apache be owner
> find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # Change directory permissions rwxr-xr-x
> find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # Change file permissions rw-r--r--
> ```
>
> After the setup you should tighten the access rights, according to
>   [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) all files except for wp-content should be
>   writable by your user account only. wp-content must be writable by
>   *www-data* too.
>
> ```
> chown <username>:<username>  -R * # Let your useraccount be owner
> chown www-data:www-data wp-content # Let apache be owner of wp-content
> ```
>
> Maybe you want to change the contents in wp-content later on. In this
>   case you could
>
> - temporarily change to the user to *www-data* with `su`,
> - give wp-content group write access 775 and join the group *www-data* or
> - give your user the access rights to the folder using [ACLs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists).
>
> Whatever you do, make sure the files have rw permissions for
>   *www-data*.

Correct me if I am wrong though :).